# Compare string with ">", "<", "=" in c

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison, implicit-conversion, c-strings

I want to know what is compared when we have s1 > s2 and what is the result (for example when we compare chars their ASCII corresponding codes are compared). I read that with this operation are compared the first chars of s1 and s2, but if I try to compare with s1[0] > s2[0] the result is different, then it cannot be that.

Comment: Does "the first chars of s1 and s2" means that s1 and s2 are strings? The result of comparing pointers to two different objects is undefined. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And about the question's title, you cannot use `=` to compare. And you can't use `<` or `>` to compare strings: please use `strcmp()`.

Comment: `s1` and `s2` contain memory adresses to the first position of the array, it is the same as `&s1[0]` and `&s2[0]`, and you would be comparing these adresses.

Comment: What Weather Vane said.  Use `strcmp` to compare strings in C, both for strict equality and for simple "dictionary order" greater and less than.

Comment: I cannot change the way to write this code. They are written by my professor but I need to understand what they did. s1 and s2 are strings, but I tried to print the two variables but the results don't seem to be addresses

Answer (score 2):

Comparing with `==` means checking if the pointers point to the same object, so this:

```
char s1[] = "foo";
char s2[] = "foo";
if(s1 == s2) 
    puts("Same object");
else
    puts("Different object");
```

would print "Different object".

`<` and `>` makes absolutely no sense unless the pointers are pointing to the same object. For instance, you could do like this:

```
char s[] = "asdfasdf";
char *p1 = &s[3], *p2 = &s[6];
if(p1 < p2) 
    // Code
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have character arrays like for example

```
char s1[] = "Hello";
char s2[] = "Hello";
```

then in an if statement like for example this

```
if ( s1 == s2 ) { /*,,,*/ }
```

the character arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

So the above statement is equivalent to

```
if ( &s1[0] == &s2[0] ) { /*,,,*/ }
```

As the arrays occupy different extents of memory then the result of such a comparison will be always equal to logical false.

If you want to compare strings stored in the arrays you need to use the standard string function `strcmp` declared in the header `<string.h>`.

For example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//...

if ( strcmp( s1, s2 ) == 0 )
{
    puts( "The strings are equal." );
}
else if ( strcmp( s1, s2 ) < 0 )
{
    puts( "The first string is less than the second string." );
}
else
{
    puts( "The first string is greater than the second string." );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following macro that might be considered a slight abuse of preprocessor.

```
#define STROP(a, OP, b) (strcmp(a, b) OP 0)
```

Examplary usage:

```
STROP(s1, >=, s2) // expands to `strcmp(s1,s2) >= 0`

STROP(s1, ==, s2) // expands to `strcmp(s1, s2) == 0`
```